# Mixed content Error LiveWire image upload

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-livewire

Help please with problem. Getting this error when trying to upload image.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://***.***/admin/posts' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://***.***/livewire/upload-file?expires=1661491099&signature=c30a70fd1588f7abfdb23c2d221e0a8d0adc587513486f7a8e4ee4a24a0128ed'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Where I need to change that request to HTTPS?

Image upload function

```
public function add_image(){
    $this->active_tab = 0;
    $this->validate([
        'photo' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max
    ]);
    $this->photo->storeAs('pics', $this->photo->getClientOriginalName(), 'pics');

    $path = Post::find($this->post_id);
    $path->path = $this->photo->getClientOriginalName();
    $path->save();

    $this->render();
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ExcelController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Code;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Task22Controller::class, 'index'])->name('home');
//Route::post('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Task22Controller::class, 'create'])->name('create');

Route::get('/auth', function () {
    if (
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '85.174.227.60'
        || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == '85.174.227.60')
        || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '62.105.135.123'
        || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == '62.105.135.123')
    ) {
        Auth::loginUsingId(1, true);
        return redirect('/admin');
    } else
        return redirect('/');
});

Route::view('/', 'main');
Route::view('/admin', 'codes')->middleware('auth');
Route::view('/admin/codes', 'codes')->middleware('auth');
Route::view('/admin/posts', 'posts')->middleware('auth');
Route::view('/admin/settings', 'settings')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/get_pict/{code}', function ($code) {
    $resp = (object)[];

    $res = Code::where('code_name',$code)->get();

    if( count($res) == 0 ){
        $resp->er = 1;
        $resp->er_text = 'Bu kod geçerli değil';
        //dd($resp);
        return $resp;
    }

    if( $res[0]->status == '1' ){
        $resp->er = 1;
        $resp->er_text = 'Bu kod geçerli değil';
        return $resp;
    }

    if( $res[0]->status == '2' ){
        $resp->er = 1;
        $resp->er_text = 'Bu kod geçerli değil';
        return $resp;
    }

    $cd = $res[0];
    $cd->status = '1';
    $cd->save();

    $sql = "SELECT path FROM posts where not path is null and status = 1 and not id = " . $res[0]->post_id . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";
    $r = DB::select($sql);
    $rnd = [];
    foreach ($r as $v) {
        $rnd[] = $v->path;
    }

    $post_id = $res[0]->post_id;
    $post = Post::find($post_id);
    $resp->er = 0;
    $resp->path = $post->path;
    $resp->rnd = $rnd;
    //dd($resp);
    return $resp;
});

Route::get('export-excel-file', [ExcelController::class, 'exportExcel']);

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Front

```
<!-- File Modal -->
    <div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="fileModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fileModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" wire:model="user_id">
                            <label for="fileInput">Choose Image</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" wire:model="photo" id="fileInput">
                            @error('name') <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary close-btn" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" wire:click.prevent="add_image()" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading your **error** I think what's happening here is that the page, you are uploading an image is `HTTPS` but the result page where your image is uploading itself is using `HTTP` so that is why your `XMLHttpRequest` is not uploading or loading anything from there.

In my guess, the problem is with this part of the code,

```
$path->path = $this->photo->getClientOriginalName();
```

try to see what is the value of the `$path->path`, is it in **HTTP** or **HTTPS**

or if you are in production you can use this below code at the beginning of your **api.php** or **web.php** file to change all **URLs** in `HTTPS`. but use this only if your env is in production because your localhost is working on **HTTP** so your pages will not work.

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```